When does a function $g\colon\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$ $g(-i\nabla)$ define an operator on $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$?
When does a function $g\colon\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$ $g(-i\nabla)$ define an operator on $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$?
The operator $g(-i\nabla)$ is defined on the Fourier side. For any $\psi\in L^2(\mathbb R^d)$, $$g(-i\nabla)\psi(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^d}\int_kg(k)\widehat \psi(k)e^{ik\cdot x}\,dk.$$
If $g\in L^\infty$, then, for any $\psi\in L^2(\mathbb R^d)$, $$\|g(-i\nabla)\psi\|_{L^2}=
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}\|g(k)\psi(k)\|_{L^2_k}\leq \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}\|g\|_{L^\infty}\|\psi\|_{L^2}$$ by Plancherel.
But every operator on $L^2$ must be represented by an integral kernel. Does this require $g\in L^2$ also?

What is $g(\nabla) \psi$ for $g\in L^\infty$ and $\psi\in L^2$? Does not make too much sense to me.

I made an edit!

If you want a well defined operator on all $L^2$, that is a bounded operator, then $g$ in $L^\infty$ is necessary ans sufficient. For unbounded operators, as long as you can make sense of it ...
